# How can I save memory for pandas data?

Tags: python, pandas

I created a Python program for analyzing cryptocurrencies. The program gets candlestick information from the exchange every minute and appends it to the pandas DataFrame object with variable name "candlesticks".

However, I noticed that this "candlesticks" variable would become very large if this program was run for a long time. In order to save memory, we decided to determine the length of the DataFrame as 50000, and then delete old data one by one when it exceeds that.

The following code is a simplified sample code.
The oldest data is deleted using the DataFrame method drop() and the new data is updated using the append() method.

```py
from random import random
import pandas as pd
import time

def get_current_candlestick():
    return pd.Series([int(random()*10)], index=["close"])

candlesticks = pd.DataFrame(dict(close=[3,2,3,4]))

while True:
    time.sleep(1) # 
    current_candlestick = get_current_candlestick()
    candlesticks = candlesticks.drop(0).reset_index(drop=True)
    candlesticks = candlesticks.append(current_candlestick, ignore_index=True)
    print(candlesticks)
```

DataFrame's drop () and append () methods are non-destructive, meaning that they are reassigned to candlesticks to keep the original data unchanged.

Here, I was worried for some reason whether this worked as a memory saver.

In the line `candlesticks = candlesticks.drop(0).reset_index(drop=True)`, a new DataFrame object with the old data removed is created and reassigned to candlesticks. However, I'm going to reassign and overwrite the candlesticks, but I thought that the old candlesticks before dropping would remain in memory.

So I ran the following code to see if the memory ID had changed before and after applying drop () to the candlesticks variable.

```py
before_id = id(candlesticks)
candlesticks = candlesticks.drop(0).reset_index(drop=True)
after_id = id(candlesticks)
print("Before ID: ", before_id, "After ID: ", after_id)
print("Same ID...? :", before_id == after_id)

# ---output---
# Before ID:  4795901992 After ID:  4795766096
# Same ID...? : False
```

I wrote poor English using google translation, so I illustrated the question graphically.

[image]

If the ID is different, does the data before overwriting remain in memory? If so, is there a way to refer to the ID and delete it using the del function, or a better way to save memory?

ーーーーAddーーーー

I was able to solve my problem with the following code, with the advice of Sosel, who I chose as the best answer.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({"a":[1, 2, 3]})
print(id(df), "\n", df)
df.drop(0, inplace=True)
df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
print(id(df), "\n", df)
df.loc[len(df)] = {"a": 1}
print(id(df), "\n", df)
# 4704449088 
#     a
# 0  1
# 1  2
# 2  3
# 4704449088 
#     a
# 0  2
# 1  3
# 4704449088 
#     a
# 0  2
# 1  3
# 2  1
```

Comment: Does it help to set "inplace = True" in your drops?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example in a nutshell:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"a":[1, 2, 3]})
print(id(df))
df = df.drop(0)
print(id(df))
# 2713481233416
# 2713618437192
```

Using inplace, the ID remains, you are changing the dataframe inplace, but appending creates a new id:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"a":[1, 2, 3, 4]})
print(id(df))
df.drop(0, inplace=True)
print(id(df))
df = df.append({"a":  5}, ignore_index=True)
print(id(df))
# 2713481233416
# 2713481233416
# 2713617869448
```

Instead of appending, maybe directly adding one line via "loc" function helps:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"a":[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]})
print(id(df))
df.drop(0, inplace=True)
print(id(df))
df.loc[len(df)] = {"a": 1}
print(id(df))

# 2713634483336
# 2713634483336
# 2713634483336
```

This answer should keep memory ID constant, but is not optimised for CPU time...

Comment: Hi, I think this will only work for the first iteration, because label 0 is dropped. The reason why the original loop works is only, that he reindexes the dataframe, so he gets a new label 0, but I think this can be avoided by fetching the first index value in each iteration.

Comment: With a dataframe you can use "reset_index" which also has the possibility of "inplace=True"

Comment: Not good, but: if you know the max length of your dataframe, you can always manually set the index using df.set_index(np.arange(0, MAX_LEN), inplace=True)

Comment: How about just using `df.drop(df.index[0], inplace=True)`?

Comment: Thank you! Your code expresses what I wanted to say more simply and clearly. And```inplace = True``` is a good solution. But I still have two questions. First, the code  ```df.loc[len(df)] = {"a": 1}``` replaces the end, not adding new data to the DataFrame. Can you improve this? Secondly, even if the memory IDs are different, it is sufficient if the memory of the data before overwriting is released as a result. Does my overwritten description free the memory of the data before overwriting?

Comment: Writing a dictionary on the element `len(df)` does add an element at index `len(df)`, and since resetting let the index let's the dataframe start with index zero, this really is appending at the end of the dataframe.